# Why String.IndexofAny() is working differently in Framework 4.6 from .NET50

Tags: c#, frameworks, console-application, .net-5

I have to return the text based on the input format used in formula. So,
When I used to check `String.IndexofAny()` in Framework 4.6 it returns `-1` even if the character is present.

Example :
Formula : `=TEXT(TODAY(),"MMMM");`

textFormat = "MMMM";

char[] formats = { 'M', 'D', 'Y', 'S', 'T' };

| Condition | Framework 4.6 | .NET50 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `textFormat.IndexofAny(formats)` | -1 | 0 |

Can someone help me with the exact reason and solution?

Comment: [I cannot reproduce this.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UO3fzL) Can you copy/paste a compliable repro?

Answer (score 2):

In the docs, they have a site about the topic.

[Behavior changes when comparing strings on .NET 5+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/string-comparison-net-5-plus)

Comment: @priya-nandhini If this answer satisfies your question, please mark it as Accepted by clicking the check mark in the top left. :)

Comment: I agree. This is the best answer for the question.